# Web-scraping text from unstructured webpages, using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nlp

I'm looking to take all the relevant text sections of text of certain web pages and parse it into a structured format, e.g. a CSV file for later use. 
However, the web pages I want to take info from don't strictly follow the same format, for example, the pages:

`http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/groupings/machine-learning/
http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/groupings/robotics/
http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/groupings/reasoning/`

I have been using BeautifulSoup and this has been fine for the web pages that follow a well-defined format, but these particular websites don't follow a standard format. 
How can I write my code to extract the main text from these pages? 
Could I either extract all the text and strip away the irrelevant/commonly occurring text?
Or can I somehow select these larger text bodies even though they don't occur uniformly? 
The websites are formatted differently but not in such a convoluted way that I think this is impossible?

Originally I had code like this for dealing with the structured pages:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/tom/PycharmProjects/tmc765/Parsing/MScProject.db')
c = conn.cursor()


### Specify URL
programme_list = ["http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/0144",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/9502",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/452B",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/4436",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/5914",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/9503",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/9499",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/5571",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/5955",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/4443",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/9509",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/5576",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/9501",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/4754",
              "http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/programmes/2017/5196"]

for programme_page in programme_list:
# Query page, return html to a variable
page = urlopen(programme_page)

soupPage = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

name_box = soupPage.find('h1')
Programme_Identifier = name_box.text.strip()

Programme_Award = soupPage.find("td", text="Final Award").find_next_sibling("td").text
Interim_Award = soupPage.find("td", text="Interim Award")
if Interim_Award is not None:
    Interim_Award = Interim_Award = soupPage.find("td", text="Interim Award").find_next_sibling("td").text
Programme_Title = soupPage.find("td", text="Programme Title").find_next_sibling("td").text
School_Department = soupPage.find("td", text="School/Department").find_next_sibling("td").text
Banner_Code = soupPage.find("td", text="Banner Code").find_next_sibling("td").text
Programme_Length = soupPage.find("td", text="Length of Programme").find_next_sibling("td").text
Total_Credits = soupPage.find("td", text="Total Credits").find_next_sibling("td").text
UCAS_Code = soupPage.find("td", text="UCAS Code").find_next_sibling("td").text
Awarding_Institution = soupPage.find("td", text="Awarding Institution").find_next_sibling("td").text
QAA_Benchmarking_Groups = soupPage.find("td", text="QAA Benchmarking Groups").find_next_sibling("td").text

#SQL code for inserting into database
with conn:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Programme_Pages VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
              (Programme_Identifier, Programme_Award, Interim_Award, Programme_Title,
               School_Department, Banner_Code, Programme_Length, Total_Credits,
               UCAS_Code, Awarding_Institution, QAA_Benchmarking_Groups, programme_page))

print("Program Title:           ", Programme_Identifier)
print("Program Award:           ", Programme_Award)
print("Interim Award:           ", Interim_Award)
print("Program Title:           ", Programme_Title)
print("School/Department:       ", School_Department)
print("Banner Code:             ", Banner_Code)
print("Length of Program:       ", Programme_Length)
print("Total Credits:           ", Total_Credits)
print("UCAS Code:               ", UCAS_Code)
print("Awarding Institution:    ", Awarding_Institution)
print("QAA Benchmarking Groups: ", QAA_Benchmarking_Groups)
print("~~~~~~~~~~\n~~~~~~~~~~")

Educational_Aims = soupPage.find('div', {"class": "programme-text-block"})
Educational_Aims_Title = Educational_Aims.find('h2')
Educational_Aims_Title = Educational_Aims_Title.text.strip()

Educational_Aims_List = Educational_Aims.findAll("li")
print(Educational_Aims_Title)
for el in Educational_Aims_List:
    text = el.text.strip()
    with conn:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Programme_Info VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (Programme_Identifier, text,
                  Educational_Aims_Title, programme_page))
    print(el.text.strip())
```

However, I've not found a way yet to write a script to pull out the relevant text from the unstructured pages I've linked above. 
I was considering trying to pull all the sections tagged

and then processing them as they come. 
I just thought someone might have any insight on an easier way.

Comment: Please, give us a code sample to show what you already have tried.

Comment: I think you will need to hard code every single link separately as there is no script which sees the website the way human eye sees and understands what user would like to save into the file. If you would upload your existing scripts it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I've added the code I've used on the structured equivalent pages, but my code for handling the unstructured pages doesn't really have any meat to it yet since I'm not sure how best to approach it. 
Even a suggestion in the right direction would help.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends, what kind of information you want to extract. In my example, I extracted title, text and staff list (if exists). You can add additional parsing rules for extract more information:

```
urls = ['http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/groupings/machine-learning/',
'http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/groupings/robotics/',
'http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/groupings/reasoning/']

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pprint import pprint

for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

    # parse title
    title = soup.select_one('h1.title').text

    # parse academic staff (if any):
    staff_list = []
    if soup.select('h2 ~ ul'):
        for li in soup.select('h2 ~ ul')[-1].find_all('li'):
            staff_list.append(li.text)
            li.clear()
        soup.select('h2')[-1].clear()

    # parse the text
    text = ''
    for t in soup.select('nav ~ *'):
        text += t.text.strip() + '\n'

    print(title)
    print(text)
    print('Staff list = ', staff_list)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Will print (abbreviated):

```
Intelligent Robotics Lab


Welcome to the Intelligent Robotics Lab in the School of Computer Science at the University of Birmingham. ...

Staff list =  []
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Reasoning

Overview
This grouping includes research on various forms of reasoning, including theorem proving and uncertain reasoning, with particular application to mathematical knowledge management, mathematical document recognition, computer algebra, natural language processing, and multi-attribute and multi-agent decision-making. The research is relevant both to understanding how human reasoning works and to designing useful practical tools...


Staff list =  ['John Barnden', 'Richard Dearden', 'Antoni Diller', 'Manfred Kerber', 'Mark Lee', 'Xudong Luo', 'Alan Sexton', 'Volker Sorge']
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Cheers man! That's not exactly the way I'm trying to do it but that's a big help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty structured to me:- these pages

1. always have a title
2. maybe have a header
3. maybe `<ul>` or a bunch of `<p>` or mix and you can you can check for all

finally, to print all the paragraphs in the right order you have to take a look at checking the element from top-to-bottom for more info take a look at this question  [[Access next sibling]](http://Access%20next%20sibling%20%3Cli%3E%20element%20with%20BeautifulSoup%20Ask)

Comment: You're right in that they do still have quite a lot of structure, the header is always there, the sidebar is (often) the same.
So I could just iterate through the blocks and skip the top and sidebar, that'd be the easiest way you think?

Comment: all you have to do is to extract the main tag and examin each child of it by it's order if it's either ul or p or header or even a title then extract its text and push it into a list

Comment: So there's more than one main tag but it looks like the first one is always a top bar. So I can just take everything from the main and pull out all the text? 
Am I correct in thinking I have to do like, a findall() for the types, e.g. ul, p, h2 etc I have to look for them specifically? Or can I just do fetch next sibling?

Comment: '<div class ="main-row">' actually there is only one of that .. check it's elements one by one if the tag is either p or h1 or h2 or ul you can grab the text. then the job is done!